# flask-sqlalchemy relationship between tables issue

Tags: python, database, flask, database-design, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build dashboard for admins who can manage some settings about their organizations.

below are 2 tables, Users and Organization, when someone register it supposed to create the user and organization with relationship between them, but after I try to register I get the following error
(sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: user.org_id)

which makes sense, but i'm not sure how can I create the user and the organization that he belongs to and also add the organization ID in the user table at the same time?

or is this database design wrong?

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    display_name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    date_joined = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default="default.jpg")
    org_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("organization.id"), nullable=False)



class Organization(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    domain = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    date_joined = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    logo_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default="default.jpg")
    sub_type = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default="Demo")
    sub_start_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    sub_end_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    status = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default="Active")
    admins = db.relationship("User", backref="admin", lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.email}')"
```

```
    @users.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def register():
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(url_for("main.dashboard"))
        form = RegistrationForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode(
                "utf-8"
            )
    
            organization = Organization(
                domain=form.email.data.split("@")[1],
            )
            admin = User(
                first_name=form.first_name.data,
                last_name=form.last_name.data,
                display_name=form.first_name.data + " " + form.last_name.data,
                email=form.email.data,
                password=hashed_password,
            )
            db.session.add(organization)
            db.session.add(admin)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("Your account has been created! You are now able to log in", "success")
            return redirect(url_for("users.login"))
        return render_template("users/register.html", title="Register", form=form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have nullable set as False on User.org_id, you will need to assign the org_id to the User when you first create it. You should create the organization first, then create the user with org_id assign to it.
Your code should look something like this instead

```
organization = Organization(
            domain=form.email.data.split("@")[1],
        )
        db.session.add(organization)
        db.session.commit() #Need to create the organization first to obtain the id
        admin = User(
            first_name=form.first_name.data,
            last_name=form.last_name.data,
            display_name=form.first_name.data + " " + form.last_name.data,
            email=form.email.data,
            password=hashed_password,
            org_id=organization.id
        )
        db.session.add(admin)
        db.session.commit()
```